# how to hide the div card if API data is empty

Tags: php

Hi everyone i am trying to get Data from Api ,some of them will display empty means there is not any data right but the div card still displaying so i am here to seek for help which i want to hide the div card if it is empty

```
function getRoom($room){
        $rooms= array();
        $img = "";
        $name = "";
        $description = "";

        $rooms['img'] = $img;
        $rooms['name'] = $name;
        $rooms['description'] = $description;
        $rooms['address'] = $address;

return $rooms;
}


function getRoomCard($room){
        if (empty($room)){
            echo "No trace currently found";
          }
       
        return "
        <div class='col-md m-1'>
            <div class='card h-100'>
                <img class='card-img-top' src='{$room['img']}' alt='Card image cap' style='width:100%;height:180px;background-size: cover;'>
        
                <div class='card-body'>            
                    <h3 class='card-title'>{$room['name']}</h3>
                    <h5='card-text description'>description : {$room['description ']}</h5>
                    <h5='card-text description'>Address: {$room['address']}</h5>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        
        ";  
  
    }
```

Comment: if $room has no data, you can `return` early, maybe just after `echo`; or, set a CSS class with `display:none`, and so on...

Comment: return an empty string from `if (empty($room)){ return '' }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `return` in the if statement to return a string when `$room` is empty.

See [PHP Documentation: control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php) - the articles on the right have documentation and code examples to learn how they work.

You should not use `echo` in the `if` statement. Your function *either* prints something *or* returns something - so just return the text.

```php
function getRoomCard($room){
  if (empty($room)){
    return 'No trace currently found';
  }
 
  return "
  <div class='col-md m-1'>
      <div class='card h-100'>
          <img class='card-img-top' src='{$room['img']}' alt='Card image cap' style='width:100%;height:180px;background-size: cover;'>
  
          <div class='card-body'>            
              <h3 class='card-title'>{$room['name']}</h3>
              <h5='card-text description'>description : {$room['description ']}</h5>
              <h5='card-text description'>Address: {$room['address']}</h5>
          </div>
  
      </div>
  </div>
  
  ";  

}
```

You also have some minor mistakes in the HTML. This does not matter for your current question, but you probably forgot " class" after the `h5` tags:

Incorrect:

```php
<h5='card-text description'>description : {$room['description ']}</h5>
<h5='card-text description'>Address: {$room['address']}</h5>
```

Fixed:

```php
<h5 class='card-text description'>description : {$room['description ']}</h5>
<h5 class='card-text description'>Address: {$room['address']}</h5>
```